# MLP, logistic regression with very badly prediction on training data set

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, neural-networks, python

I have a problem with my MLP model (one hidden layer, wrote from scratch in python). When I'm trying to solve logistic regression problem with 3 (1, 2, 3) classes, and first train on training data set, next try to make prediction, and when I'm predicting on the test dataset, acurracy is >90%, but when I'm trying to make prediciton on the training dataset, acurracy is very bad. I also tried to append test and training datasets and train on this summary data set and after that try to predict apart test and training data set and results was very good. I tried on many different hyperparameter settings, but the result was similar. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Hi sorry i am a bit lost. You are saying you get 90% accuracy on your test set with logistic regression, but it's bad on the train set? I don't get how is it even fitted in the first place... Is it possible to expand on your question a bit with more information?

Comment: Hi sorry i am a bit lost. You are saying you get 90% accuracy on your test set with logistic regression, but it's bad on the train set?" - Yes, exactly.

I'm using SGD to train network with one hidden layer and various (1-20) neurons therein. I've tried to train with and without bias, with various learning rate and momentum. Size of my data set and training set are the same, 90. I have to use 1-4 features for predicted object. It's project to pass course at university so I can't change size of the data set, 
I have to use the ones I received.

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive. Can you post your code & data?